# Receive the position of my viewpager in my main form

Tags: android, xamarin

I use a viewpager like carousel that contains three images, so I want to get the position that each one is 1, 2, 3 and show me as a message

Example: if I drag to the second it returns me 2, if I move to 3 it returns me 3

```
// my form
 ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
 var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
 viewPager.PersistentDrawingCache = Android.Views.PersistentDrawingCaches.ScrollingCache;
 viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
```

And this is my class:

```
   public class ImageAdapter : PagerAdapter
   {
    private Context context;
    private string[] imageList = {
        "image1",
         "image2",
          "image3",};

    public ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return imageList.Length;
        }
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        return view == ((ImageView)objectValue);
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(View container, int position)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imageView, imageList[position]);
        ((ViewPager)container).AddView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    public override void DestroyItem(View container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        ((ViewPager)container).RemoveView((ImageView)objectValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            System.out.println("position = " + position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where should I put it? In my form

Comment: error :  @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                System.out.println("position = " + position);
            }

Comment: my project xamarin android